# Using demonstratives with time periods

Tags: time, demonstratives

I want to express 'These past one and a half years...'.  E.g. 'These past one and a half years have been really fun!'

What I've come up with so far is: この一年半間で。。。[past tense].

I think I've just made the mistake of literally translating it though.

Answer (score 3):

It is 「この[一]{いち}[年半]{ねんはん}」.

You **cannot** add 「[間]{かん}」 to it, but you **can** 「の[間]{あいだ}」.

The "rule" is that we just cannot say 「～～[半間]{はんかん}」.

> ***Correct:***: 「この1年半」、「この1年半の[間]{あいだ}」、「この2[週間半]{しゅうかんはん}(の[間]{あいだ})」, etc.
>
> ***Incorrect***: 「この一年半[間]{かん}」、「この2週間半[間]{かん}」,
> etc.

「この」 can, of course, be replaced by 「その」 or 「あの」 depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks.

If I want to emphasise that a period of time has passed, is adding「の間」better, or is it superfluous?

Comment: Google gives many examples of "一年間半", many seemingly by native speakers, although I agree that "一年半" sounds better.